# how to store all data in database after success payment using payumoney?

Tags: php, payumoney

I trying to integrate payumoney on checkout page. It's work but some flieds not store in database like lastname, city, state. So, where i do mistake and don't understand. Please find what going wrong. I using test mode payumoney. Below, i Provide my code what i tryed.

checkout form:-

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" name="payuForm">                      
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $MERCHANT_KEY ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="surl" value="<?php echo $surl ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="furl" value="<?php echo $furl ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h5>Review & Payment</h5><hr/>
      <?php 
        $checkout = new Checkout();
        echo $checkout->finalCheckout();
      ?> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h5>Shipping Details</h5><hr/>
      <?php $productinfo = json_encode($_SESSION['productinfo']); ?> 
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="productinfo" value='<?php echo $productinfo; ?>'>

      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstname">First Name*</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['firstname'])) ? '' : $posted['firstname']; ?>">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastname">Last Name*</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['lastname'])) ? '' : $posted['lastname']; ?>">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email*</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['email'])) ? '' : $posted['email']; ?>">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="phone">Mobile*</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['phone'])) ? '' : $posted['phone']; ?>">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="address1">Address*</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address1" name="address1" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['address1'])) ? '' : $posted['address1']; ?>">              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="country">Country*</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" name="country" value="India" disabled="disabled">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="state">State*</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" id="state" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="city">Town/City*</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="zipcode">Postcode/Pincode*</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" maxlength="6" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['zipcode'])) ? '' : $posted['zipcode']; ?>">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div><hr>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="GO BACK">
           <?php if(!$hash){ ?>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="CONTINUE">
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

PayUMoney integration code:-

```
<?php
  //CARD NO: 5123456789012346
  //CARD VAILD: 05 20
  //CARD CVV: 123
  $MERCHANT_KEY = "hDkYGPQe";
  $SALT = "yIEkykqEH3";
  // Merchant Key and Salt as provided by Payu.

  $PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in";    // For Sandbox Mode
  //$PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://secure.payu.in";      // For Production Mode

  $surl = "http://localhost/neelam/success.php";
  $furl = "http://localhost/neelam/failed.php";
  $action = '';

  $posted = array();
  if(!empty($_POST)) {
      //print_r($_POST);
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {    
        $posted[$key] = $value;                            
    }
  }

  $formError = 0;

  if(empty($posted['txnid'])) {
    // Generate random transaction id
    $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
  } else {
    $txnid = $posted['txnid'];
  }
  $hash = '';
  // Hash Sequence
  $hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";
  if(empty($posted['hash']) && sizeof($posted) > 0) {
    if(
        empty($posted['key'])
        || empty($posted['txnid'])
        || empty($posted['firstname'])
        || empty($posted['lastname'])   
        || empty($posted['email'])
        || empty($posted['phone'])
        || empty($posted['address1'])
        || empty($posted['zipcode'])
    ) {
      $formError = 1;
    } else {
        //$posted['productinfo'] = json_encode(json_decode('[{"name":"tutionfee","description":"","value":"500","isRequired":"false"},{"name":"developmentfee","description":"monthly tution fee","value":"1500","isRequired":"false"}]'));

        $hashVarsSeq = explode('|', $hashSequence);

        $hash_string = '';  
        foreach($hashVarsSeq as $hash_var) {
            $hash_string .= isset($posted[$hash_var]) ? $posted[$hash_var] : '';
            $hash_string .= '|';
        }

        $hash_string .= $SALT;

        $hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hash_string));
        $action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
    }
  } elseif(!empty($posted['hash'])) {

    $hash = $posted['hash'];

    $action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
  } 
?>
```

And here success page i store data in databse:-

```
$status=$_POST["status"];
$txnid=$_POST["txnid"];
$firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
$lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
$amount=$_POST["amount"];
$txnid=$_POST["txnid"];
$posted_hash=$_POST["hash"];
$key=$_POST["key"];
$productinfo=$_POST["productinfo"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$phone=$_POST["phone"];
$address=$_POST["address1"];
$country=$_POST["country"];
$state=$_POST["state"];
$city=$_POST["city"];
$state=$_POST["state"];
$pincode=$_POST["zipcode"];
$salt="yIEkykqEH3";

INSERT INTO wm_orders(firstname,lastname,email,phone,address,country,state,city,pincode,productinfo,txnid,amount,payment_status,delivery_status) VALUES('{$firstname}','{$lastname}','{$email}','{$phone}','{$address}','{$country}','{$state}','{$city}','{$pincode}','{$productinfo}','{$txnid}','{$amount}','{$status}','N')
```